# WCF Client of REST Web Service - Fail after few requests

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, iis

I created a wcf service and host it in IIS, it is working fine upto now.

Now i have list of records and i run a loop through all the records and send them to my bll using my WCF rest service. It serves two requests well, but at the third request it throws Time Out Exception and put the blame on one of my method in BLL.

If method has any flaw in it then it should not process the first two records also.

I don't know if there is any setting in IIS or in WCF service that is blocking such frequent requests.

Comment: What specifically is the exception. What's the stack trace? What's the code? You're not really giving much in the way of specifics to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One have to increase the number of parallel connections we could make.

Settings in config file would be these

```
 <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add maxconnection="65535" address="*"/>
    </connectionManagement>    
  </system.net>
```

Comment: you are not specifying where to add this system.net namespace  in web.config file , In my case i hit the browser 49 times and then request error comes , In my request error log , it says Timeout exception ! , can u help me with this. and simply you resolved the error by adding the answer that you accepted ?

Answer (score 0):

In the config file there is an option where you can specify the time up to which client will wait for the response from the service. If Service will not respond up to that time, TimeOut Exception occurs.

Comment: Where is the place so i can specify the time? i ran into this problem from last two days.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to close your connection to the service once you complete your call.  The default number of connections you can have from your machine to the service over HTTP is 2.  If you don't close the connections once you're done, your third connection will starve waiting for its turn.

Comment: How to close the connection and how to increase default number of connections on my machine. I am using "using" statement while creating HttpClient object, i believe it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

In your config file, add

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0"/>
```

under

Chandana